SOQL Select in VF controller not retrieving record created prior
I have something strange happening here.  I have an Apex class that created a new record (Invoice) and I pass that record Id into a controller (indirectly through a callable class), the id is valid, but for whatever reason that record is not available to the controller.  If I remove the where class in the controller I do get back all of the invoice records except the one that was just created.  So I am not really sure why this is not working.  Also, I am executing all of this logic as a sys admin user so I would not think sharing rules would apply...
public without sharing class PDFGeneration {
public static blob saveInvoicePdf(Id accountId, Boolean invoiceSent, String startDate, String endDate, String groupId, String groupBy) {
    system.debug('bw: saveInvoicePdf-->' + accountId + ' ' + invoiceSent + ' ' + startDate + ' ' + endDate + ' ' + groupId + ' ' + groupBy);

    Blob body;
    Timesheet__c timesheet = new Timesheet__c();
    Basic_Invoice__c insertInvoice = new Basic_Invoice__c();
    decimal amount = 0;
        
    timesheet = [SELECT Id, Basic_Invoice__c, Employee__c,
                        (SELECT Id, Expense_Amount__c FROM Expenses__r WHERE Basic_Invoice__c = NULL),
                        (SELECT Id, Bill_Amount__c FROM Timesheet_Entry_Slots__r )
                FROM Timesheet__c
                WHERE Id = :groupId];
    system.debug('bw: saveInvoicePdf, timesheet = ' + timesheet);

    for(Timesheet_Entry_Slot__c slot : timesheet.Timesheet_Entry_Slots__r) {
        amount += slot.Bill_Amount__c;
    }

    for(Expense__c expense : timesheet.Expenses__r) {
        amount += expense.Expense_Amount__c;
    }

    insertInvoice.Provider__c = timesheet.Employee__c;
    insertInvoice.AccountId__c = accountId;
    insertInvoice.Amount__c = amount;
    insertInvoice.Due_Date__c = Date.today().addDays(30);
    insertInvoice.Hours__c = 0;
    insertInvoice.Invoice_Date__c = Date.today();
    system.debug('bw: saveInvoicePdf, insertInvoice = ' + insertInvoice);
    
    Database.SaveResult dbResult = Database.insert(insertInvoice); //<---INSERT

    timesheet.Basic_Invoice__c = insertInvoice.Id;
    timesheet.Status__c = 'Processed';
    update timesheet;

    List<Expense__c> expensesToUpdate = timesheet.Expenses__r;
    if(expensesToUpdate.size() > 0) {
        for(Expense__c expense : expensesToUpdate) {
            expense.Basic_Invoice__c = insertInvoice.Id;
            expense.Status__c = 'Processed';
        }
        update expensesToUpdate;
    }

    if (dbResult.isSuccess()) {
        id invoiceId = insertInvoice.Id;
        body = doGenerateDocs(invoiceId, accountId, startDate, endDate, groupId, groupBy);
    }

    return body;
}

public static Blob doGenerateDocs(id invoiceId, id accountId, String startDate, String endDate, String groupId, String groupBy) {
    List<Basic_Invoice__c> invoiceList = [SELECT Id, Name
                                          FROM Basic_Invoice__c
                                          WHERE id = :invoiceId]; //<---VERIFIES EXISTS


    system.debug('Alll');
    system.debug(invoiceList[0].Name);
    // EXECUTE VF PDF PAGE (RENDERAS="PDF")
    String pageName = 'invoicePDF';//getPageNameInvoice();

    Map<string, object> args =  new Map<string, object>();
    Map<string, object> params = new Map<string, object>();
    map<string,string> argsMap = new map<string,string>();

    args.put('pdfPageName', pageName);
    params.put('invoiceName', invoiceList[0].Name);
    params.put('invoiceId', invoiceId);
    params.put('id', accountId);
    params.put('endDate', endDate);
    params.put('startDate', startDate);
    params.put('group', groupId);
    params.put('groupBy', groupBy);
    args.put('params', params);

    Callable generator = (Callable) Type.forName(null, 'umPDFGenerator').newInstance();
    blob body = (Blob) generator.call('savePDF', args);
}
}

global with sharing class umPDFGenerator implements Callable {
private Blob savePDF(string pdfPageName, map<string,object> params) {
    String partialPageUrl = '/apex/' + pdfPageName;
    PageReference pdf = new PageReference(partialPageUrl);
    Blob body;

    for(string key:params.keySet()) {
        pdf.getParameters().put(key,(string) params.get(key));
    }

    try {
        body = pdf.getContent();
    } catch (VisualforceException e) {
        body = Blob.valueOf('Error : ' + e + ' :: page = ' + partialPageUrl);
    }

    return body;
}

global Object call(String action, Map<String,Object> args) {
    switch on action {
        when 'savePDF' {
            string pdfPageName = (string) args.get('pdfPageName');
            Map<string,object> params = (Map<string,object>) args.get('params');
            return this.savePDF(pdfPageName, params);
        }
        when else {
            throw new MalformedCallException('Method not implemented');
        }
    }
}

global class MalformedCallException extends Exception {}
}

public class Controller_InvoicePDF {
private umInvoice m_inv = new umInvoice();
private id invoiceId;
public umInvoice inv {
    get {
        return m_inv;
    }
}
  
public Controller_InvoicePDF() {
    id accountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    date endDate = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('endDate') != null ? date.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('endDate')) : date.today();
    string startDateStr = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('startDate');
    date startDate;

    if(startDateStr == null) {
        startDate = endDate.addMonths(-100).toStartOfMonth();
    }else{
        startDate = date.valueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('startDate'));
    }

    string groupBy = 'Timesheet';//ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('groupBy');
    Id groupId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('group');
    Id invoiceId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('invoiceId');
    if(invoiceId != null) { //<--- ID IS VALID
    Basic_Invoice__c inv = [SELECT Id, AccountId__c
                                            FROM Basic_Invoice__c
                                            WHERE Id = :invoiceId
                                            LIMIT 1]; //<--- NO RECORD FOUND
    accountId = inv.AccountId__c;
    
    List<Timesheet__c> tsInfo = [SELECT id, Placement__r.Work_Location_Name__c, Placement__r.Client_Name__c,
                                    Placement__r.Billing_Account__r.Name
                                    FROM Timesheet__c
                                    WHERE Basic_Invoice__c = :invoiceId];       
        if(tsInfo.size()>0){
        this.m_inv.billingAccount = tsInfo[0].Placement__r.Billing_Account__r.Name;
        this.m_inv.client = tsInfo[0].Placement__r.Client_Name__c;
        this.m_inv.workLocation = tsInfo[0].Placement__r.Work_Location_Name__c;  
        }

    }
    this.invoiceId = invoiceId;
}
}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

If you can add whole process step by step like this method is inserting the record then callable class and last this method is trying to query record that will be helpful in debugging this.
